# ExtJS 4 - Apply CSS to grid headers individually

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, grid, extjs4

I'm trying to apply some CSS to the headers (just the headers themselves - not the entire column) in a grid.  Should be fairly easy I'd think but haven't been able to figure it out.

I've set up a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6en2r/) that contains a grid. I'd like the `Name` header to be bold, and the `DOB` header to be red.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I uncomment cls in your columns definitions it works on fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your CSS:

```
.x-column-header-text{color:blue;}
```

to change headers individually use:

```
.x-column-header-text#gridcolumn-1011-textEl{color:blue;}
.x-column-header-text#gridcolumn-1012-textEl{color:red;}
```

check: http://jsfiddle.net/6en2r/1/

forgot to mention the nth-child selector:

```
.x-column-header:nth-child(2){color:red;}
.x-column-header:nth-child(1){font-weight:bold; color: black;}
```